# Network Profile Button grayed out

Tags: support, profile-page

I noticed that the "Network Profile", in the upper right corner, is grayed out when on Meta. This doesn't seem to be the case on any of the other sites I visit. Please refer to the picture below:

[image]

Is this supposed to happen? I would assume not, since this button doesn't lead to your "Meta" page, but your *network* page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's greyed out because you're on a "hidden" community. The greying is intended to remind you of that and to indicate that only you can see that link to your network profile (along with site mods).

You'll find it looks the same on your other hidden site profile pages, say [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/343387/linny).